# How can I read an array of doubles with mmap from text file

Tags: c, arrays, file, 2d, mmap

I tried this:

```
double *mat = (double *) mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

where sb.st_size is the size of the file and fd is the descriptor of the opened file. 
If I want to iterate through all the elements I get only 0s, but the file has only non 0 values. What is wrong with this?

Comment: `double *` is not a 2D array.

Comment: I considered the 2D array as a 1D because it seemed easier. Not a very helpful answer

Comment: Not a very helpful question. A 1D array is not a 2D array. A rabbit is not a fox! Oh, and comments are not for answering, you want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

If you truly have a text file, then you have text numbers, almost like a spreadsheet:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
1.1 2.1 3.1
```

You cannot `mmap` that file and treat the mapped memory as `double*`, because that is *character* data.

In order to convert the file from character data to doubles, you will have to do something like `fscanf` or `scanf` to process the digits.

On the other hand, if you wrote out a blob of doubles as *binary* data, then you could do the `mmap`, pretty much as you describe.